# Python classes: linked attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes

Is there a more pythonic way of 'linking' attributes such that when one attribute in a class is changed, another can be automatically changed according to some relation that I define?

Currently, I'm doing something like:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2 * self.x
        pass
    def set_x(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = 2 * self.x
        return
A = myClass()
print A.x #prints 1
print A.y #prints 2
A.set_x(5)
print A.x #prints 5
print A.y #automatically changes to 10
```

Comment: Incidentally, [recommended Python style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is to capitalize all words in class names while using lowercase words (separated by underscores) for variable names, thus `a = MyClass()` rather than `A = myClass()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use properties:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x
        self.y = 2 * self._x
```

And a test:

```
>>> c= myClass()
>>> c.x = 10
>>> c.x
10
>>> c.y
20
```

Comment: The second line of `__init__` setting `y` manually is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use getters and setters:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    @property
    def y(self):
        return 2 * self.x
    ...
```

Basically, this is saying is when you try to get A.y, it returns self.x * 2 instead.

And considering the rest of the class, I would actually do something like this:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 1

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return 2 * self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self._x = val
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see why you make `x` a property if all you do with the getter and setter is get and set `_x` instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's a decent point.  Habit I guess. That way if you need to change it later the code and private variable are already there.