# Python classes: both ways linked attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11944436/10172674) it is discussed how to create a pair of linked attributes (*x* and *y*), such that when one is changed, the other is changed automatically. The way it was solved, however, makes so that this is a one way process: updating *x* changes *y*, but updating *y* directly keeps *x* unchanged. What I need is to make the link symmetric, so that changing *y* also changes *x*. The solution I have come up so far is this:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x
        self._y = self._x * 2
        
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        self._y = y
        self._x = self._y / 2
```

What I don't like about this solution is that I find it clutters the class quickly. I will want my class to have several linked attributes in the future, so I wanted a way to make this code more concise. Is there a simpler or smarter way to do this?

Comment: You can simplify slightly by using one setter from another but otherwise not really.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify what you mean by using one setter from another?

Comment: Well the y setter could just be `self.x = y / 2`.

Comment: Oh , I see. Thanks!